# How to call Pandas read_sql_query only if it returns rows

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Working on this [open source sql client](https://github.com/brianrisk/qwaver) and am at a roadblock with using Pandas' `read_sql_query`.  The issue is that the client needs to execute any SQL query, even something that does not return rows such as:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cows;
```

Running the above with `read_sql_query` produces the following error:

> ResourceClosedError at /path
> This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

However, if the query does return rows, like a normal `SELECT`, then I do want the results as a Pandas DataFrame.

Is there a better solution than simply catching the `ResourceClosedError`?  Is perhaps `read_sql_query` not the appropriate function?

Comment: I'm so confused. Why would you _want_ to wrap around a DROP TABLE via a pandas method?

Comment: The scope, at least to me on the surface and I've had a quick scan of your library README, seems to have crept. I'm not sure _how_ you might stop people executing arbitrary SQL but it certainly doesn't feel like it should be going through `read_sql_query` even if just for the namesake, let alone the behaviour

Comment: FWIW I generally use `sqlalchemy` for this kind of thing, even if I intend to make a df afterwards. I don't like the `pandas` choice in wrapping SQL (it made a mess of `executemany` for a while on `psycopg2`, for example, and I'd rather not be bound by its decisions). It's trivial to execute queries on an `engine` and _then_ convert to a `df`, which you could just look at the `.empty` property of, and not worry about it crashing out.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the comments.  I don't necessarily want to wrap a drop table around a Pandas function, but I do want to execute any SQL and if it returns rows to have the results in some way translated to a DataFrame.  I think your last comment which recommends a manual process is the direction that may need to be taken.

Comment: I can flesh that out if you want as an answer, but I _will_ be stripping `pandas` SQL out of the equation